# How to disable VS Code Git yellow icons next to my files?

Tags: python, html, git, github, visual-studio-code

I am using Git in Visual Studio Code, and there are icons next to my files - U (untracked) and M (modified). They are useful sometimes, but most of the time I just find it really distracting and annoying. Is there any way of turning it off so I don't see it?
Notice the yellow M next to my files.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJXQW.png]

Answer (score 4):

The Git status tags in Explorer/file view can be toggled using the Decorations option for the Git extension.

If you want to disable it for every project, search `decorations` in `Settings` and uncheck `Git > Decorations: Enabled`.

If you just want to disable it in your current project, add the following rule to your project settings in `.vscode/settings.json`:

```
    "git.decorations.enabled": true
```

Comment: most likely it is `false` and it can also be done for the Workspace with the Settings GUI